Google Sheets AppScript Data Integration Error
I am trying to send the data from my React App to Google Sheets using Google AppScript. But what error I am facing is that the data integrated is jumbled partially. Here's the code of my React App:
const Questions = () => {
  const user = useSelector((state) => state.user);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!sessionStorage.id) {
      navigate("/");
    }
  }, [navigate]);

  const [currentQuestionIndex, setCurrentQuestionIndex] = useState(0);
  const [selectedOptions, setSelectedOptions] = useState(
    Array(questionsData.length).fill(null),
  );
  const totalQuestions = questionsData.length;
  const currentQuestion = questionsData[currentQuestionIndex];
  const [showSelectOptionError, setShowSelectOptionError] = useState(false);

  const optionWords = [
    ["rationalizing", "trivializing", "compromising", "projection"],
    ["trivializing", "projection", "rationalizing", "avoiding"],
    ["projection", "rationalizing", "displacement", "trivializing"],
    ["avoiding", "rationalizing", "denial", "trivializing"],
    ["rationalizing", "trivializing", "avoiding", "compromising"],
    ["attacking", "avoiding", "compromising", "compensation"],
    ["projection", "attacking", "rationalizing", "trivializing"],
    ["avoiding", "compensation", "displacement", "intellectualization"],
    ["denial", "projection", "rationalizing", "trivializing"],
    ["substituting", "rationalizing", "trivializing", "intellectualization"],
  ];

  const onSelect = (option) => {
    const updatedSelectedOptions = [...selectedOptions];
    updatedSelectedOptions[currentQuestionIndex] = option;
    setSelectedOptions(updatedSelectedOptions);
    setShowSelectOptionError(false);
  };

  const handleNext = () => {
    if (selectedOptions[currentQuestionIndex] !== null) {
      setCurrentQuestionIndex((prevIndex) =>
        Math.min(prevIndex + 1, totalQuestions - 1),
      );
    } else {
      setShowSelectOptionError(true);
    }
  };

  const handlePrev = () => {
    if (showSelectOptionError) {
      setShowSelectOptionError(false);
      setCurrentQuestionIndex((prevIndex) => Math.max(prevIndex - 1, 0));
    }
    setCurrentQuestionIndex((prevIndex) => Math.max(prevIndex - 1, 0));
  };

  const handleSubmit = async () => {
    const userData = {
      name: user.name,
      email: user.email,
      education: user.education,
      gender: user.gender,
      dateOfBirth: user.dateOfBirth,
    };

    const data = {
      ...userData,
      ...selectedOptions.reduce((acc, option, index) => {
        if (option !== null) {
          const wordOption = optionWords[index][option - 1];
          acc[`question${index + 1}`] = wordOption;
        }
        return acc;
      }, {}),
    };

    const proxyUrl = "http://localhost:8080/";
    const targetUrl = import.meta.env.VITE_GoogleAppScript;
    console.log(data);

    try {
      const params = new URLSearchParams(data);
      const body = params.toString();

      const response = await fetch(`${proxyUrl}${targetUrl}`, {
        method: "POST",
        body: body,
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        },
      });

      console.log("\n\nData recieved: " + response);

      dispatch(setUserDetails(initialUserState));
      sessionStorage.clear("id");
      navigate("/thankyou");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error:", error);
    }
  };


And here's my Google AppScript code:
const sheets = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("google-sheet-url");
const sheet = sheets.getSheetByName("sheet-name");

function doPost(e) {
  const data = e.parameter;

  console.log("Received Data:", data);

  const name = data.name;
  const email = data.email;
  const education = data.education;
  const gender = data.gender;
  const dateOfBirth = data.dateOfBirth;
  const question1 = data.question1;
  const question2 = data.question2;
  const question3 = data.question3;
  const question4 = data.question4;
  const question5 = data.question5;
  const question6 = data.question6;
  const question7 = data.question7;
  const question8 = data.question8;
  const question9 = data.question9;
  const question10 = data.question10;


  sheet.appendRow([name, email, education, gender, dateOfBirth, question1, question2, question3, question4, question5, question6, question7, question8, question9, question10]);

    const response = ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(data));
  response.setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  response.setStatusCode(200);
  const headers = {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://localhost:3000"
  };
  return response.setResponseHeaders(headers);
}

[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/oJcNfObA.png)
I tried every possible debugging, but do not know why the server side changes the data format

I have debugged the error, actually the fault was that the Google AppScript was running under previous deployment. Remember to deploy every time whenever you make any changes to the code.


const sheets = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("google-sheet-url");
const sheet = sheets.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

function doPost(e) {
  const data = e.parameter;
  console.log("Received Data:", data);

  const rowData = [
    data.name,
    data.email,
    data.education,
    data.gender,
    data.dateOfBirth,
    data.question1,
    data.question2,
    data.question3,
    data.question4,
    data.question5,
    data.question6,
    data.question7,
    data.question8,
    data.question9,
    data.question10,

  ];

  sheet.appendRow(rowData);

  return ContentService.createTextOutput("Data Appended Successfully!");
}



Everything works fine now.
